# Theorem numbering without the section and subsection numbers

Tags: numbering, theorems

I wish to number my theorems within subsections as

Theorem 1
Theorem 2
Theorem 3
...

And only reset it back to 1 when I have a new subsection.

So I have a subsection within a section, and within the subsection I have several theorems, which are normally numbered section.subsection.theoremnumber.
But I want it just to be Theorem 1, Theorem 2, Theorem 3, etc until the end of the subsection, and in the next subsection, reset it back to Theorem 1, Theorem 2, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use, and also if you use a theorem-related package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`. Separately, should the change in numbering system apply only to `theorem` environments, or should it apply to other, theorem-like environments, e.g., `proposition`, `lemma`, `corollary`, etc.?

Comment: Please advise if your document currently features an instruction such as `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]`.

Answer (score 9):

Specify the theorem to renew with every `\subsection`, and then remove the `subsection` counter from the theorem counter representation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]% theorem counter resets every \subsection
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}% Remove subsection from theorem counter representation

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `thethm` referring to?  I haven't been able to figure out how to use this with my `amsart` article. What do I need to replace `thethm` with in that context?

Comment: @rschwieb: `\thethm` refers to the representation of the counter `thm`; internally, the `thm` acts like a counter, but it's representation -
 `\thethm` - can be something arbitrary (like `\roman{thm}` for lowercase Roman numerals, `\Roman{thm}` for uppercase Roman numerals, `\alph{thm}`, `\Alph{thm}`, ...). This counter is defined when you define the `thm` environment via `\newtheorem{<env>}{.}[.]` that holds your theorem content. How did you define your theorem environment?

Comment: I'm not sure what things are relevant, but here goes nothing: I'm using `amsart`, and I use the `amsmath` and `amsthm` packages, and I see  `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` .  My goal is to have global sequential numbering throughout the paper (Theorem 1, Proposition 2, Theorem 3, etc. across the entire document, regardless of sections)

Comment: @rschwieb: `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` defined a `theorem` environment (so you can use `\begin{theorem}` ... `\end{theorem}`) that prints the title `Theorem X`. Here `X` is the `theorem` counter representation, or `\thetheorem` and will be prefixed with the `\section` counter representation (or `\thesection`) separated by a period `.`. So if you want to change your `theorem` counter representation, you'd need to `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{...}`.

Comment: @rschwieb: Based on your requirements - a global continuous counter for different environments - you'll need to use `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` and then subsequent environments `\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}`, `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}`, ... See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/zfZAZDz8).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... this is beginning to click. There is a Remark that is intruding into my numbering, but I don't want it to. How can I define it so that it's available, but does not need a counter, and does not use the theorem/proposition counter?

Comment: @rschwieb: You should probably use `\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}`, which prints `Remark.` *without* a counter and doesn't interfere with other environments' numbering.

Comment: Thank you! It's been a long time since I learned anything much about this, but today was very helpful. Everything is as it should be, now.